# Sequence of saving list of items from android app to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm saving list of items (by adding item one by one) from my app to firebase database, when I add 10th element it got saved after 1 (key) node not below 9th one and 2nd got shifted below 10 as you can see in the image below . And list of items are shown in the RecyclerView in the same sequence as it is saved in firebase databse . Why are the items  saved in such a manner??

[image: list of items in firebase database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviors. Keys in the Firebase Realtime Database are strings, and they are shown in so-called lexicographical order.

If you'd use letters, you'd also expect this order:

- a
- b
- ba
- c

And it is no different for numbers when they are sorted lexicographically, as they are here.

If you want to see a numeric sort order, consider padding the numbers to a fixed with, for example by prefixing them with zeroes:

- crop: 000
- crop: 001
- crop: 002
- ...
- crop: 010

Note that in general using such numerical sequential values as keys is an anti-pattern in Firebase, and it's recommended to use its built-in push keys instead. For more on this see: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! is there any way to sort the list except built-in push keys? What if wanna save list of items manually in firebase database then retrieving them in app?? Is there any way to generate push keys manually ??

Comment: The algorithm is fully documented, and the code is available. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html To learn about other ways to sort data, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data